# Configure DNS for Windows Service Bus Namespace DNSEntry

Tags: azure, servicebus, azureservicebus

Windows Service Bus 1.0 supports DNS-registered namespaces using `New-SbNamespace -AddressingScheme DNSRegistered`.

[New-SbNamespace command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj248744%28v=azure.10%29.aspx)

My Scenario:

1. All machines on same domain (cromwell.local)
2. 2 Compute Nodes
3. 1 SQL Node on separate server
4. 2 namespaces (NamespaceA & NamespaceB for example)

Should the DNS entry (I'm leaning CName - not a DNS guru) each point to a compute node?  That doesn't seem to give with the whole gateway/redirect situation.

Comment: I want to be clear this is for the on-premise version of the Service Bus, not the Azure version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter what kind of entry, as long as you have a host name that maps to an IP (or set of IPs, if you're using a clustered install). The host name can be a simple name (e.g. my-server) or a fully qualified domain name (e.g my-server.mydomain.com). What's important is that the name can be resolved by both parties, and that you pass the same host name to the server when creating the namespace.

One important thing to consider is that the hostname you use must match the CN name ofthe server's ssl certificate, to avoid auth issues (due to CN name matching). If you're using a default install on a domained-joined machine, you should use a hostname with the same domain name (since in default installs on a domain the server uses a *.yourdomain cert). For all the other scenarios (workgroup machines, hostname that doesn't match the domain) you'll need to provide your own cert. This decision will impact the namespaces you'll be able to have on the server (since all of them will need to match the certificate CN somehow), so weight well your options.

---

Based on the scenario you describe, I recommend you do the following:

- Your DNS name should point to the IP of both compute nodes (I'm assuming these are the machines running service bus server. Besides the DNS redirection, this will also give you DNS-based load balancing
- You can only have one namespace per DNS name, so when creating Namespace A you need to pass the CNAME you created on the first step. If you need to have more namespaces, you'll need to create more CNAMEs (which could be a problem with your certificate, depending the hostname / domain names you're picking)

PS. Service Bus Server doesn't really support a 2-node configuration. You should either go to one node for simplicity, or three, if you want a highly-available server.

Comment: Thanks Ramiro - this helps a lot.  I've described my scenario in more detail based on your response.  Does that help pinpoint my question a little more?

Comment: Great, I'll edit my answer based on the rest of the information.

Comment: I was more interested in configuration of multiple nodes and automating the deployment with webpicmd /offline and wbs ps cmdlets.  Why do you say it doesn't support two nodes?  Effectively fails over to the second if node one goes down, correct?

Comment: Due to the way clustering is implementented on Service Bus, you'll need three server to get true High Availability. On a two server setup you might see some failover initially, but after a few minutes your cluster will get very unstable.